# VBA to Retrieve Value of Worksheet-Scoped Defined Name That Contains a Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call the result of a worksheet-scoped named formula in VBA and can’t get it to work.  The VBA is doing a number of things that are working fine, but here is the simplified setup for the problematic portion.  On a sheet named ThursTest, there is a named range “Blob” whose formula is “=$J$1&B$2&$I3” if cell B3 is selected (the result of that formula will depend on which cell on ThursTest is selected since the column for the second component and the row for the third component are variable).  I am trying to loop through a bunch of cells on that sheet, check the value for Blob and then do something if the value matches the value from another table.  Note that “Blob” is NOT the formula for any of those cells.  I want to get the value of Blob as if it were entered in the active cell.

In my VBA, I have shtSched defined as a Worksheet and set to ThursTest, “BlobSched” defined as a string, and shtSched.Range(“B3”) active.  I want to set BlobSched to equal the value of the worksheet range “Blob” for the active cell.  I have tried shtSched.Range("Blob").Value, shtSched.Range("Blob").Text, and Evaluate(shtSched.Range("Blob")), but all fail with run-time error 1004 (Method ‘range’ of object ‘_Worksheet’ failed).  How can I set the VBA term BlobSched to equal the results of the worksheet defined range/formula Blob for the active cell?

Here is an excerpted version of my VBA:

```
Sub stackoverflowtest1()

Dim shtData As Worksheet 'tab with schedule data
Dim shtSched As Worksheet 'the tab where schedule blocks will be created
Dim tData As ListObject 'the data table "SchedData"
Dim BlobSched As String 'blob as named range in sheet, which is a formula
Dim rSched As Range 'range of Schedule
Dim dBlob As Range 'this is the contents of the Blob column on the data tab WITHOUT the header
Dim cols As Double 'this is the number of data columns per day
Dim rows As Double 'this is the number of data rows per day
Dim cSched As Range 'a single cell on Schedule tab
Dim cData As Range 'a single cell on Data tab
Dim x As Integer 'counter

'Setup
    Set shtData = Worksheets("Data")
    Set shtSched = Worksheets("ThursTest")
    cols = 7
    rows = 123
    Set rSched = Range(shtSched.Range("Start"), shtSched.Range("Start").Offset(rows - 1, cols - 1))

    Set tData = shtData.ListObjects("SchedData")
    Set dBlob = tData.ListColumns("Blob").DataBodyRange
    
'Work through cells in shtSched, compare to data source
    For Each cSched In rSched
        x = 0
        cSched.Activate 'change to activate?  select?  set?
        BlobSched = shtSched.Range("Blob").Value
        'BlobSched = shtSched.Range("Blob").Text
        'BlobSched = Evaluate(shtSched.Range("Blob"))
        
        For Each cData In dBlob
            x = x + 1
            If cData.Value = BlobSched Then
                'do something
            Else
                'do something else
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: can you use the EVALUATE() function?  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/evaluate-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the definition of your name. As far as I'm aware you can only call the `.Range` property if the name is actually defining a range. If your name is defining a formula then you need to use the `Names` property. Here's an example:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print "Sheet1.Range(""Blob_range"").Value"
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("Blob_range").Value 'works.
    Debug.Print IIf(Err.Number = 0, "worked", "failed") & vbNewLine: Err.Clear
    
    Debug.Print "Sheet1.Range(""Blob_formula"").Value"
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("Blob_formula").Value 'fails.
    Debug.Print IIf(Err.Number = 0, "worked", "failed") & vbNewLine: Err.Clear
    
    Debug.Print "Sheet1.Names(""Blob_formula"").Value"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(Sheet1.Names("Blob_formula").Value) 'works.
    Debug.Print IIf(Err.Number = 0, "worked", "failed"): Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Below is an image of my name manager:

[image]

and the immediate window shows:

> Sheet1.Range("Blob_range").Value  5  worked
>
> Sheet1.Range("Blob_formula").Value failed
>
> Sheet1.Names("Blob_formula").Value  3  worked

Comment: Perfect.  I changed "BlobSched = Evaluate(shtSched.Range("Blob"))" to "BlobSched = Evaluate(shtSched.Names("Blob").Value)" and it pulls the value just as I wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Good luck with your project. BTW, nicely constructed question - concise, with sample code. Wish we had more like that.